# How To Clear A MapIcon by Title UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, bing-maps, uwp-maps

Does anyone know how to clear a specific MapIcon. 
I have an app that tracks me and I'm using the clear() method to remove my icon and then it regenerates it in my new location. However, another function grabs locations from a database and plots those on the map when I push a button. 
I don't want those POI to be cleared when my code updates my location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list of MapIcons by using Linq, for example use a `Where` to select only the MapIcon you want by checking some of the MapIcon's property.

If you don't know how to use Linq or you need some other explanation please tell me in the comments and add some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. And yes, I'm not good with linq. The only unique property that the mapicons have is the title. I know the name of the mapicon I want to remove and there is only 1 always. So I don't need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I reworked my way of plotting my location. I now have a function "InitMyLocation()" that initializes my position on the map. The UpdatePosition event just updates my position and doesn't re add a new mapicon element.

So I call my function in the MainPage() and then when my app clears the map elements from the other functions, the other functions now call my InitMyLocation() and voila... I'm back in business.

Thank y'all!